Shot noise limited detection
can somebody please explain the significance of shot noise limit? I am trying to understand why and how shot noise degrades image quality, for e.g., while imaging weakly scattering specimens using an optical microscope? The field is detected using a CMOS or EMCCD sensor. I am not able to get an intuition about this.

Shot noise is the noise it light itself. If you had a 1000 pixel camera and shone it at a uniform light source you would find each pixel collected a different amount …. It’s not the camera it’s the light ….all light has the noise.

Shot noise is caused by the quantum nature of light. I assume you're familiar with the idea. Speaking loosely, light is described by a wave function that spreads like in classical wave optics, but on interaction with the detector, it collapses into a photon. The position on the photon is random, but the probability distribution is given by the square of the wave function.
In your experiment, you want to determine this probability distribution, but what you actually measure are the photons. That's not much of a problem if you measure a lot of photons thanks to the law of large numbers. The law of large numbers says (again loosely speaking) that if you do a random experiment lots of times, your results look like you'd expect given the probabilities. But for small numbers, that isn't guaranteed.
For an illustration: photons follow Poisson statistics, so for a median of $N$ photons, you have a standard deviation of $\sqrt{N}$. So if you have an image with a constant mean measurement of 10000 photons, you get a standard deviation of 100 photons, but for a darker image with a mean of 100 photons, you get astandard deviation of 10, so the relative error increases as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, from 1% to 10%.

oh yes, that helped. Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!

Shot noise also applies to detectors that count electrons. Moreover, if the signal has shot noise (Poisson distribution, $\lambda$) and is detected with something that has probability of detection (Bernoulli distribution, $\epsilon$), then the signal is a convolution of the two distributions, which is still shot noise: Poisson with $\lambda' = \epsilon\lambda$. If that signal is then amplified in a chain, e.g. a PMT, the signal follows Pólya distribution.
